# In conda virtual environment,how to use " sudo python exampy.py" without using the version of python in system?

Tags: python, anaconda

When I use anaconda to create a virtual environment named tf-py36 and activate it, By using

`python test.py`

It warns that I don't have the permission. But when I use

`sudo python test.py`

it uses the version of python in my system which isn't the one in the virtual environment.

How can I solve this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

this occurs because `$PATH` is different between your user and root.

An indepth discussion is given here: https://superuser.com/questions/600349/why-sudo-python-and-python-in-terminal-start-two-different-versions-python

in order to use your anaconda version of python type the following command:

`sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python <enter python command>`